# Java Driver throws null pointer on cursor.hasNext()

Tags: java, mongodb

Java Driver throws null pointer exception on cursor.hasNext()

```
_collection  = db.getCollection("users");
DBCursor cursor = _collection.find();
System.out.println( "cursor len " + cursor.size() );
//outputs: "cursor len 2"

try {
   while(cursor.hasNext()) { //Throws null pointer exception
       System.out.println(cursor.next());
   }
} finally {
       cursor.close();
}

mongo shell:
db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51be2534036412d6b648354b"), "name" : "dude" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51be4de19234ec062efe4a53"), "name" : "lewbowski" }
```

why?? :(

Stack trace:

```
Jun 16, 2013 5:28:36 PM com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError
WARNING: emptying DBPortPool to localhost/127.0.0.1:27017 b/c of error
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.v2d2.data.UserDAO.put(UserDAO.java:166)
at org.bson.BasicBSONCallback._put(BasicBSONCallback.java:174)
at org.bson.BasicBSONCallback.gotObjectId(BasicBSONCallback.java:143)
at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decodeElement(BasicBSONDecoder.java:160)
at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder._decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:79)
at org.bson.BasicBSONDecoder.decode(BasicBSONDecoder.java:57)
at com.mongodb.DefaultDBDecoder.decode(DefaultDBDecoder.java:61)
at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:83)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:142)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:92)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:244)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:273)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:368)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:459)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:484)
at org.v2d2.data.UserDAO.<init>(UserDAO.java:76)
at MongoTest.main(MongoTest.java:41)
```

===========================================================

I fixed the null pointer but I am no closer. When I try to get the values out of the class they are returning null.

public class UserDAO implements DBObject {

```
private String _name;
private String _id;

private ArrayList<String> _buildServers;
private BasicDBObject _dao;
private DBCollection _collection;


public UserDAO() {  }

public UserDAO(
        String name,
        DB db )
{
    _name     = name;
    _dao      = new BasicDBObject();

    _collection  = db.getCollection("users");


    _dao.put( "name", _name);

    DBCursor cursor = _collection.find();

    System.out.println( "curso len " + cursor.count() );
    try {
       while(cursor.hasNext()) {
           System.out.println( ((UserDAO)cursor.next()).GetName() );
       }
    } finally {
            cursor.close();
    }
}

public void SetName( String value )
{
    _name = value;
}

public String GetName()
{
    return _name;
}

@Override
public boolean containsField(String arg0)
{
    return _dao.containsField( arg0 );
}

@Override
@Deprecated
public boolean containsKey(String arg0)
{
    return _dao.containsKey( arg0 );
}

@Override
public Object get(String arg0)
{
    return _dao.get( arg0 );
}

@Override
public Set<String> keySet()
{
    return _dao.keySet();
}

@Override
public Object put(String arg0, Object arg1)
{
            //Error was being thrown in here added null check but I can't set the values
    if( _dao == null ) _dao = new BasicDBObject();
    return _dao.put( arg0, arg1 );
}

@Override
public void putAll(BSONObject arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    _dao.putAll( arg0 );
}

@Override
public void putAll(Map arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    _dao.putAll( arg0 );
}

@Override
public Object removeField(String arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _dao.removeField( arg0 );
}

@Override
public Map toMap()
{
    return _dao.toMap();
}

@Override
public boolean isPartialObject()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _dao.isPartialObject();
}

@Override
public void markAsPartialObject()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    _dao.markAsPartialObject();
}
```

}

Comment: What does cursor.count() return? Can you check?

Comment: can you post the stack trace

Comment: cursor.count returns the same as size: 2

    Jun 16, 2013 5:28:36 PM com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError
    WARNING: emptying DBPortPool to localhost/127.0.0.1:27017 b/c of error
    java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException at org.v2d2.data.UserDAO.put(UserDAO.java:166)` -- What is at this location? That is the source of your error.

Comment: I guess the main lesson here was to just use inheritance and extend the BasicDBObject... instead of implementing the interface and trying to wrap the BasicDBOject.

Comment: When I run your UserDAO I get a ClassCastException on this line:
System.out.println(((UserDAO) cursor.next()).GetName());
This is not surprising, since by default collection.find() will return an iterator of BasicDBObject, not your custom UserDAO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is in

```
public Object put(String arg0, Object arg1)
{
    //Error was being thrown in here added null check but I can't set the values
    if( _dao == null ) _dao = new BasicDBObject();
    return _dao.put( arg0, arg1 );
}
```

as you've pointed out.

This is because this method is being called by the driver itself when you're retrieving items from the database.

So you do some sort of `find()` on your collection, and the driver recognises that it needs to create a new `UserDAO` object for the values being returned from that `find()`.  It will create a brand new `UserDAO` object (using the default constructor, the one that takes no arguments) and then call `put()` to set the appropriate values from the database on your new `UserDAO` object.

Because the object was a shiny new one create using the default no-args constructor, at this point your `_dao` field was null and empty.  You are correctly dealing with this by doing a null check and creating a new one if required.  However, this does mean that all the other fields you set up in the other constructor (the one that takes a name and a DB) are not initialised, because that constructor was never called.

If all the fields need to be initialised for all new objects, you need to create a common initialisation method that can be called where you are currently creating the new `BasicDBObject` for the `_dao` field.  However, you're going to have trouble with this as you will not know what the DB field (for example) should be.

Basically the problem is that your UserDAO should not have a reference to the DB it comes from.  I know that sounds contrary to what a DAO does, but that's because using MongoDB via Java does not follow the same sort of patterns as using a SQL database with JDBC.  The DAO pattern is not really suitable in this case.